# Can't get right solution for this polar problem...

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Given:

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=2$$

$$y = r(\sin\theta)=(3 \theta+\sin \theta)(\sin \theta)$$

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{dy}{d \theta}\right)}{\left( \dfrac{dt}{d \theta}\right)} =  \dfrac{dy}{d \theta}\cdot \dfrac{d \theta}{dt} = \text{ ??}$

Yes, where $\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{3}$ and am supposed to get an answer of -2.819

Comment: What is $x$ here?

Comment: Simple differentiation is what you have to do....... what other kind of help do you want?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I suppose $x = r \cos \theta$ but _OP_ needs to state that.

Comment: @ja72 I suspect he wants $\frac{dy}{dt}$, not $\frac{dy}{dx}$, as the subsequent steps show.

Comment: Who knows really???

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, where $\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{3}$ and am supposed to get an answer of -2.819

Comment: Yes, supposed to find dy/dt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with value $-2.819...$ because the derivative of

$$\rho = r(\sin\theta)=(3 \theta+\sin \theta)(\sin \theta)$$

with respect to $\theta$ is

$$(3 +\cos\theta)(\sin \theta)+(3 \theta+\sin \theta)(\cos \theta)$$

whose value for $\theta=2 \pi/3$ is $\sqrt{3}-\pi=-1.40954$.

Then, you just have to multiply by the other derivative, i.e., multiply by 2...

**Remark**: notation $y$ is very misleading as some colleagues remarked it. It  should be replaced (as I have done) by $r$ or $\rho$.

Comment: I get the same derivative expression, but I am not getting the same result when I plug in $2 \pi/3$ into the sins and cosines.    I get $\pi + 2\sqrt{3}$  (before multiplying by the 2)

Comment: Check that you enter the right values:  $\cos 2 \pi/3=-1/2$ and $\sin 2 \pi/3=\sqrt{3}/2$. Thus the value of the derivative is $(3 -1/2)\sqrt{3}/2+(2 \pi+\sqrt{3}/2)(-1/2)=5\sqrt{3}/4-\pi-\sqrt{3}/4$ whence the result.

Comment: OHH!   $cos(2\pi/3)$ is negative!   It's is 120 degrees, which is in 2nd quadrant. ATSC.  Right?

Comment: Got it.  Thanks so much for your time, JeanMarie!